# Python | NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: python, json, api, request, webhooks

i have a json response as a string inside a json list
as you in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4fvp.png)

i trying to get the value inside the string i tired to use eval()
but output shows me this error `NameError: name 'null' is not defined`
i can't read the json values when they are a string
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g4iJ.png)

this is my code :

```
 url = "https://api.pipedream.com/v1/sources/code/event_summaries? 
 expand=event"
 headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer hash "}
 response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
 data = response.text
 datas = json.loads(data)
 darts = datas['data']
 for i in darts:
   trake = i['event']['body']
       for docz in trake:
         open_time = open_time = docz['open_time']
         print(open_time)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFXyi.png)

the problem is the json values are string i cannot detect values

**By the way the Bearer Authorization is just a demo**

Comment: Could you post a [mre] instead of these unaligned chunks of code that do not reproduce the problem you are describing?

Comment: Man better remove the bearer token

Comment: Tried to reproduce the problem but copy-pasted code will not work due to indentation issues.

Comment: @khelwood ok i'll try to give more informations

Comment: @Abdopy Not *more*, just *better*.

Comment: @khelwood check right now ... just see the pictures and you understand the problem is i cannot detect json values because the json value is inside a list as a string

Comment: @DawidGacek is just a demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you needed is inside a dict key. So, you need to use `.keys()` attribute to retrieve it and then you have to use `json.loads()` to convert it to a dictionary.

Please check the below code:

```
import requests
import http.client
import json
from ast import literal_eval as evall


url = "https://api.pipedream.com/v1/sources/code/event_summaries?expand=event"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer hash"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


data = response.text
datas = json.loads(data)

darts = datas['data']

for i in darts:
    trake = i['event']['body']
    for docz in trake:
        print(docz)


for tracks in darts:
    tracks = json.loads(list(tracks['event']['body'].keys())[0])
    print(tracks)
    
    open_time = tracks['event']['trade'].get('open_time', '')
    close_time = tracks['event']['trade'].get('close_time', '')
    Lots = tracks['event']['trade'].get('lots', '')
    balance = tracks['event']['account'].get('balance', '')
    symbol = tracks['event']['trade'].get('symbol', '')
    profit = tracks['event']['trade'].get('profit', '')
    total_profit = tracks['event']['trade'].get('total_profit', '')


    msg = """

      Open time :  """ +open_time + """
      Close time :  """ +close_time + """
      Symbol : """ +symbol + """
      lots : """ +Lots + """
      Balance : """ +balance + """
      """


    print(msg)
    print("success")
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)